# How to store bytearrays in hashmap or hashtable in java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

Hi i have bytearrays of size 8 bytes each and i need to store them in a hashmap or hashtable. For example say i have 1000 blocks... then it will store 1st key and value(bytearray) and then when block2 is passed it should check if it is already present in hahtable and if not there it should increment and count should be incremented. I have written code to store but the problem is that it is not able to search, may be bacuse of the way i'm storing in byte array.

Code:

```
int collisions = 0;
Hashtable<Integer, Long> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Long>();
// Given bloc1 value here
if(ht.contains(bloc1)) {
  collisions++;
}
else {
  ht.put(i,ByteBuffer.wrap(bloc1).getLong());
}
```

Problem is: ht.contains is not giving the desired o/p

Comment: So you want to search for the byte array, Or the key, before you add a new byte array?  This problem really needs code.

Comment: Please show your attempt, especially after mentioning you have code

Comment: You need to edit your question to be more clear before we can help you. Are the byte arrays keys or values? If they are values then there is no problem and your error is elsewhere. Please also explain the problem you are having in more detail.

Comment: I need to store byte array in values ... and key will just increment when i'm adding new value..

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is say i have 1000 byte arrays of size 8 bytes.. i need to find collisions..

Answer (score 0):

`byte[]` objects, and other array objects in Java has `equals()` method inherited from `Object`, i. e. comparing by reference, not by array contents.

The simpliest way to resolve your problem (without additional dependencies to libraries) is to store 8-byte arrays as `long`s:

```
Map<Long, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
...
// map.put(byteArray, value);
map.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).getLong(), value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
            int collisions = 0;
           Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
          // Given bloc1 value here
             if(ht.contains(ByteBuffer.wrap(bloc1).getLong()))
                {collisions++;}
                else {
                ht.put(i,ByteBuffer.wrap(bloc1).getLong());
                }